# How to handle errors with ValueNotifier

Tags: flutter, state

I have a `ValueNotifier` class that performs some logic, then alerts all listeners when done.  The problem I have is how to alert the listeners when there is an error in the processing so that an appropriate message can be displayed in the UI.

Here is the `ValueNotifier` class:

```
class LoginStateNotifier extends ValueNotifier<LoggedInStates> {
  LoginStateNotifier(LoggedInStates value) : super(value);

  Future<void> login({required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

      print(userCredential);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      switch (e.code) {
        case "invalid-email":
          throw (Constants.invalidEmail);
        case "user-disabled":
          throw (Constants.userDisabled);
        case "user-not-found":
          throw (Constants.userNotFound);
        case "wrong-password":
          throw (Constants.wrongPassword);
        default:
          throw ("${e.code} is an invalid FirebaseAuth exception");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw ("DEBUG: ${e.toString()} - occurred in login()");
    }
  }

  Future<void> logOut() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
}
```

Here is the widget in the UI that is listening for changes:

```
        ValueListenableBuilder<LoggedInStates>(
          valueListenable: _loginScreenController.loginStateNotifier,
          builder: (context, loggedInStates, child) {
            return loggedInStates == LoggedInStates.loggedIn
                ? Text(
                    'Logged In',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                  )
                : Text(
                    'Logged Out',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                  );
          },
        ),
```

I just need a way for the listener to know when errors occur as well, not just when the value changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, probably not the most optimal, but the solution I gave to this problem was to create a second valueNotifier to propagate custom exceptions as:

```dart
abstract class CustomException implements Exception {
  final String message; // Note that this message is for logging not displaying to the user

  CustomException(this.message);
}

class ExampleAuthException extends CustomException {
  final int remainingAttempts;

  ExampleAuthException({required this.remainingAttempts, required String message}) : super(message);
}
class ErrorNotifier extends ValueNotifier<CustomException?> {
  ErrorNotifier(CustomException? value) : super(value);
}
class ViewState{
final ErrorNotifier errorNotifier;
final LoginStateNotifier loginState;
...
}
```

I make it nullable as to now when there are no errors, and I use this as a second communication channel.

Comment: thanks a lot. that worked.  but, i wonder if there is a solution that doesn't require another notifier, such as what's used in https://pub.dev/packages/error_notifier_for_provider?

Comment: Well other solutions that come to my mind are using streams or futures that communicate errors or using discriminated unions like Either or Result (see [dartz](https://pub.dev/packages/dartz)) that model an `object` as having two possible states and you could use something like Either<LoggedInStates,CustomException> as the value of your notifier. What are your thoughts on this @Darrell

Comment: This is my first Flutter app, so those solutions seem fairly complex and what you provided is easily understood and work.  So, I will continue with your original solution for now and make note of the others for future reference as my experience grows.